# Annotation apps with different layers of highlighting

Tags: pdf, annotation

Are there PDF annotation apps available that allow for different layers of highlighting?  For example, you could highlight a sentence yellow and, at the same time, some specific words within that sentence blue. Then you could cycle through different views of highlighting wherein you could see (a) just the yellow highlight, (b) just the blue highlight, or (c) both colors at the same time.

Does this exist?

Comment: Can you add [a few more details](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), especially concerning the OS your wanted solution should work on?